# Difference between varchar(max) and varchar(n)

Tags: sql-server

I have never thought of this question until recently I was troubled by one of my tasks:

So, in my store procedure, I declare a parameter `@temp_address` with datatype `VARCHAR`.

This `@temp_address` will temporary store the result from multiple columns, for example:

```
SET @temp_address = (Select Address1 + Address2 + City + State + ZipCode + Country 
FROM some_table)
```

Because I don't really know exactly the combined size of - now the complete - address, I simply use `VARCHAR(MAX)`. However, my boss rejected my work and told me not to use `MAX`, and I have to specify a size.

While it is possible for me to figure out the maximum possible size (by looking at each columns' size and sum them up), I'm just really curious, why do we need `VARCHAR(N)` instead of just simple `VARCHAR(MAX)`?

Same goes to `NVARCHAR(MAX)` vs `NVARCHAR(N)`

Comment: You might look into the MS documentation. It explains this quite clearly. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the link. However, it only tells us when to use which, but not why

Comment: It'd be nice to know what your boss said about why not to use MAX. It sounds like it's another cargo cult rule of thumb that people don't understand but insist on anyway because that's what they were told, probably due to something that was true 10 versions ago.

Comment: http://rusanu.com/2010/03/22/performance-comparison-of-varcharmax-vs-varcharn/

Comment: Well, the MS documentation talks about columns and your code just declares a variable. Even so I wouldn't go by the Rusanu performance tests as mentioned by @Lamak; instead, I would perform my own tests using my specific scenario and see what happens (and then I would defy my boss about his concerns ha ha).